# how to check to see if object is loaded before binding using jquery

Tags: jquery, load, bind

I am dynamically loading a "stub" file which contains HTML objects using jQuery. After it loads I want to bind events to the loaded objects.

My external file might look something like this:

```
<div id='myDiv'>click me</div>
```

My function looks like

```
$("#dataCol").load(fName).promise().done(function(){
    // bindings  
    $("#myDiv").click(function(){
       // do something
    });
});
```

I keep reading that "promise-load" is the way to be sure objects are loaded. Even using load.promise.done doesn't always work, and I end up setting an arbitrary setTimeout value to be sure stuff is loaded or using something like

```
$(document).on("click","#obj",function(){// do something });
```

which seems unnecessary.

I think either my premise is wrong, or I don't understand how to properly bind objects. My question is: How can I always be sure a dynamically loaded object is ready to be bound with an event?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research, it seems the newest best approach is to use

```
$(document).on("click","#obj",function(){// do something });
```

then use .on() and .off() to unbind/rebind objects